# Reading URL, Error occurred while sending Google FCM push Notification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our FCM Push Service is working fine from last 1 year in Prod but suddenly it's stopped & getting below:

FCMPushNotificationService- ***Reading URL, Error occurred while sending push Notification!..sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target***

For local server no issues, but for Prod why it's coming I don't know & unable to resolve too.

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try "downloading the certificate of FCM from googleapis.com and importing it into your JDK keystore file" as have been mentioned in this [github forum](https://github.com/bytefish/FcmJava/issues/16)?

Comment: I already tried this but same error. Anything else you can help.